# Problema al subir web hecha con React JS a Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Estoy teniendo problemas para subir una web hecha con React a Githubpages.
Cuando la subo la web lo unico que carga es el background pero nada mas.
[image: error]

En el modo development funciona sin problema.

[image: web en development mode]

Comment: Por favor agrega los mensajes de error que muestra la consola

Comment: A mi no me dio ningun problema tu página https://jmvillaltas.github.io/react-gif-app/  https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0QVA.png

Answer (score 0):

no se como lo estaras haciendo, pero quizas los atributos que asignas al importar los elementos al archivo principal HTML estan mal. Estaria bueno que des mas info para ayudarte.
Muchas veces pasa que el VS code los detecta automaticamente porque corremos el servidor nosotros, pero cuando es en el caso de GitHub Pages se lo tenemos que enseñar